# Best way to store data for a personal data science project on stocks?

Tags: python, database, storage, data-science

I have been trying to start this project for a while, I finally got to it and I am immediately stuck. The objective of my project would be to build a "bot" to trade stocks for me using stock market data. First, the data would be historical for backtesting/simulation as a proof of concept. Then the data would be "dynamic" as in added to in real-time.

First of all, I am unsure whether my data is structured or semi-structured. My first intuition was to build and use a database in MySQL, but it seems that MySQL isn't really what I am looking for here since just adding different columns to make calculations for derived variables is a huge challenge, plus Python 3 doesn't seem to like getting variables from MySQL as a program runs. So I need something that can efficiently store a large amount of stock data in, that I can easily add derived variables to such as moving averages, and something that Python 3 can easily pull data from.

I am interested in file extensions (JSON, CSV?) or systems of storing data for these kinds of projects here (DBMS?). I am new to data science and really would like to get this right so I can start building a portfolio. I am using SSH and a server running linux.

Edit:
How would this process work in a corporate environment? My understanding is that a company may store the information in an SQL DB, but would they pull from it directly for analytics/processing or would they covert to something more accessible first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of easy ways to start are [TinyDB](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (json, NoSQL) and sqlite (SQL).

If you are unsure if your data is structured or semi-structured, I would use TinyDB to get started. It is likely not to be where you wind up in the end, but may help you get something up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Storing data in files (JSON, CSV) is a good start, but it can't scale to large amounts of data.
SQLite is pretty easy to use, and the Python library is very well documented. No database server to setup, everything is stored in a file.
If you need something that can scale to large amounts of data and is easy to use with time series, you can give Influxdb a try. It's mainly used for analytics and monitoring, but it could be useful for your use case.